# Replace a sub-string

Tags: regex, pandas, replace

I'm trying to use regular expressions to replace some things in a text.

**My dataframe:**

```
       A          B                                    C
  French      house               Phone. <phone_numbers>
 English      house               email - <adresse_mail>
  French  apartment                       code : bla!123
  French      house                        Hello George!
 English  apartment   Ethan, my phone is <phone_numbers>
```

**Good output:**

```
       A          B                                    C
  French      house               Phone. <phone_numbers>
 English      house               email - <adresse_mail>
  French  apartment                        code : <code>
  French      house                        Hello George! 
 English  apartment   Ethan, my phone is <phone_numbers>
```

First, I tried this:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace(r'((ask code)|(code))\s?:?\s?\w+','<code>')
```

It works, but not completely.

```
code : bla!123
```

**Output:**

```
<code>!123
```

So, I tried this:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace(r'(ask code)|(code)\s?:?\s?), (\s?\w+)', r'\2,<code>')
```

But nothing happened...

Comment: Your first try should give `<code>!123`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Comment: @marin do you want `code : <code>` or `code : <code>!123` as output.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa code : <code>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace(r'(ask code|code)(\s?:?\s?).+', r'\1\2<code>')
```

Answer (score 2):

input:

```
 import re
 string = 'code : bla!123'
 string.replace((re.match(r'code*\s?:?\s?(.*)',string)[1]), '<code>')
```

output:

```
 'code : <code>'
```